# Incontinence flatulence

Tags: salat, wudu, incontinence

Salam Alaykum im someone who deals with incontinence flatulence and so i would have to make wudu for every prayer. But for fajr i started wudu maybe 1 or 2 mins before it actually adhan and I lost my wudu during it and I also wore socks after I finished (I started wudu before it adhan but then when it adhan I was still making wudu). But whether it was a fart or not what happens if i actually farted? Do I have to re-do my wudu again and take my socks off then put it back again or do I move on and not pray again?